# Python ctypes: get handle to already-loaded shared libraries

Tags: python, ctypes

Given a shared library's short name (e.g. gomp, not libgomp.so, etc.), what's the best way in Python to determine if that library has already been loaded and if so, find its full pathname so a ctypes handle can be obtained?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the best solution I've been able to come up with so far, but it feels a little hacky to be reading from `/proc/<pid>/maps` and doing string parsing on its contents.

```
import re, ctypes, os.path

_WHITESPACE = re.compile('\s+')

def get_loaded_lib_pathname(lib_name):
    soname = 'lib%s.so' % (lib_name,)
    pid = os.getpid()
    with open('/proc/%d/maps' % (pid,)) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            tokens = _WHITESPACE.split(line)
            addrs, perms, offset, dev, inode, pathname = tokens[:6]
            basename = os.path.basename(pathname)
            if basename.startswith(soname):
                return pathname
    return None

def get_lib_handle(lib_name):
    pathname = get_loaded_lib_pathname(lib_name)
    if pathname is None:
        return None
    return ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(pathname)

libgomp = get_lib_handle('gomp')
```